# writing binary data to a file using c++ , after receiving from socket

Tags: c++, sockets, file-io

I am trying to write a c++ code which read from a file (any type) and write the file data (binary data) on the socket , so the receiver must take this data and create a file , i should see the same data with the same format , the problem is the data is still binary and written to the file as binary data !
if a tested the code without sending on a network , it will work well !
any idea ?
thanks in advance .
note , i am using Ubuntu 11.10 if it affects this issue ..

Here is the code, on the client side:

```
filer=fopen("a.doc","rb"); 
fseek (filer , 0 , SEEK_END); 
long size; 
size = ftell (filer); 
rewind (filer); 
buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*size); 
numr=fread(buffer,1,size,filer); 
fclose(filer); //some socket code 
char buffer2[size]; 
strcpy(buffer2 , buffer);
n = write(sockfd,buffer2,size);
```

and for the server side :

```
n = read(sock,buffer,length);
FILE * filew;
int numw;
filew=fopen("acopy.doc","wb");
numw=fwrite(buffer,1,len,filew);
fclose(filew);
```

Comment: @lucas1024 : the problem is the data is still binary and written to the file as binary data !
the file should displayed as is has been read from the client host ,in the same format , not as binary !
say : .doc file with colored  font .. thats it!

Comment: huh? colored font? maybe the file extension is wrong? have you tried to rename it?

Comment: @sana could you post the code that you've tried?  It sounds like your trying to do something that netcat does very well.  I would compare binaries before and after, something like `diff -a <fileBefore> <fileAfter>`.

Comment: @MartyE
 the client side :

  filer=fopen("a.doc","rb");
  fseek (filer , 0 , SEEK_END);
  long size;
  size = ftell (filer);
  rewind (filer);

  buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*size); 
  numr=fread(buffer,1,size,filer);
 fclose(filer);
  //some socket code
  char buffer2[size] ; 
  strcpy(buffer2 , buffer);
  n = write(sockfd,buffer2,size);


and for the server side :

   n = read(sock,buffer,length);
   FILE * filew;
 int numw;
   filew=fopen("acopy.doc","wb");

   numw=fwrite(buffer,1,len,filew);
 fclose(filew);

Comment: .doc is typically an extension for a MS Word file, which is in fact binary. your mentioning of colored font seems to support this. .doc files are not text files.

Comment: @sana I placed the code in your original post.  It will make it easier for us to read that way.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you'll need to loop.  The calls to `read` and `write` will not always be the full buffer.  **Disclaimer that I couldn't test this here**
Ex:

```
numr=fread(buffer,1,size,filer); 
fclose(filer); //some socket code 
char buffer2[size]; 
strcpy(buffer2 , buffer);
n = write(sockfd,buffer2,size);
```

to

```
char buffer2[size]; 
while ((numr=fread(buffer,1,size,filer)) != 0)
{
    strcpy(buffer2 , buffer);
    n = 0;
    while ((n = write(sockfd,buffer2+n,numr-n)) != 0)
       ; 
}
fclose(filer); //some socket code 
filer = NULL;
```

Likewise on the server side

```
n = read(sock,buffer,length);
FILE * filew;
int numw;
filew=fopen("acopy.doc","wb");
numw=fwrite(buffer,1,len,filew);
fclose(filew);
```

to

```
FILE * filew;
filew=fopen("acopy.doc","wb");
int numw = 0;
while ((n = read(sock,buffer,length)) != 0)
{
    while ((numw=fwrite(buffer+numw,1,n-numw,filew) != 0)
       ;
}
fclose(filew);
```